# navigation bar borders

Tags: html, css, layout

I have been trying to figure out how to make a nav bar like this one here: [navbar](http://i50.tinypic.com/2hziusn.png)

but as almost an absolute beginner, I have no idea which method to use here. Is it a UL or a table, and also don't know how to set these borders between the links which should most probably be inserted there as the images.

I know it would be more helpful if I wrote my own code here to be examined first, but I don't even know whether I should go with the table or a list with this one. 
So, I would really appreciate if someone could give me a suggestion on that first and then i could write a code which we could discuss further.

Thanks

Comment: do you need the border to be exactly as shown in the image ?

Comment: Yes, Hasan, exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done 2 different ways. The first one will be with image of a small vertical line which will be set as a background of the navigation button.

The other way is to be an absolute positioned `<span>` in the `<a>` tag with height as this border height and set `top: 0` and `left:0`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Nav 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Nav 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    float:left; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
}

ul li a {
    display:block; 
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative; 
}

ul li span {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10px; <!-- as long as you want -->
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

You can copy and paste that in your editor and see how it looks like.

And for navigations use `<ul>` with `<li>`'s. The `<table>` is deprecated and is no longer good to use it for that purposes.

Comment: Панайот, благодаря!
I just tested this in my editor and this is exactly what I wanted to achieve,though I still don't know how to add the 5th item as an empty one and how to set different sizes for the first and the 5th item.
I know, this probably sounds very stupid, but I warned you I was a beginner :)

Comment: Ok, I made it - somehow! :) though still have one question. 
You can see what I did here: [demo][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/astronaut/afsEb/

Now, the last question, I hope.
I used padding-top and left to position links inside the boxes, but that left the place from where they originally were still clickable. So it's not only text that is clickable but also all the space created with padding. 
What should i do now to get rid of it?

Thanks again!

Comment: You should place the margin to the <li> instead of the <a>, or just use margin, but not padding.

Answer (score 0):

Although i prefer using UL for the menu,
it seems to be easier to achieve the effect with tables.

try making a table with two rows and 5 columns.

and:
remove the bottom-border of the first row.
remove the upper-border of the second row.
the borders of the cells in the second row.

also you may have to set the height of each row.

Comment: It's really not easier ... and of course layout with tables is the answer of 90's and early 2000's. If you prefer that way you've better use `display: table-cell` than tables.

Comment: i know that tables should never be used except for tabular data :)
but its seems this is be done for a homework , and by an "almost an absolute beginner".. so sometimes we should consider the situation and not just blame others (me :p) for their prehistoric answer ;)

Comment: I do not blame you, but prefer to teach others of the right way to do it. And he knew already that menu's are created with ul's  :)

Comment: and i prefer to teach others the right way too :)

so please next time instead of saying:

`It's really not easier ... and of course layout with tables is the answer of 90's and early 2000's. If you prefer that way you've better use display: table-cell than tables.`

try saying:

`Hasan, I believe this should be done with ul, because it the right way for making menus :)`

|||

^_^

Comment: So -bottom line- WE BOTH AGREE that "menu's are created with ul's" :)

Comment: Thank you both, very much! Wish I had enough reputation points to rate your answers as helpful :(

Comment: Hasan, I appreciate your answer very much too, and will certainly give it a try, but I read it a little late and had already starte playing with Panaiot's solution.

Comment: so you went the better way :)
because -as mentioned above- menus should be made with UL (or OL) 
good luck!

Comment: Yes, though i still don't know how to remove the clickable space created by adjusting the position of the link text, and also don't know how to make the first and the last box wider thn the three ones containing actual links :(
here is how i did it: http://jsfiddle.net/astronaut/afsEb/

Comment: you may use: `li:nth-child(n)` or in ur case: `li:first-child,li:last-child` and adjust their width.

Comment: regarding the clickable area you may try giving the a element the full  size of the li. dont forget to remove the a element margins and the li element padding.